# Rethrow Python exception with new type

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I have a class `NameDatabase` that opens an sqlite file. Several things
can go wrong, such as a malformed DB, a wrong schema, etc. This will generally result in
an exception (`sqlite3.Error` in my case).

I don't want to let that exception escape my class. Instead I want to give
callers my own exception classes (reasoning: besides `NameDatabase` I also have
classes for images and GPS tracks, and I want to present callers with a common
list of exceptions to deal with).

First, is this a good idea? Second, how do I best go about it?

My current code:

```
class FileParseError(...): pass

class NameDatabase:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(fname)
            # Check if we can query the DB and if the schema is ok.
            self.conn.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM names')
        except sqlite3.Error:
            raise FileParseError("Not a valid database: '%s'", fname)
```

This works, but gives a double traceback (*During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred*). What I'd ideally have is the original traceback, along with an exception of my own type `FileParseError` (which can store some info about the original exception).

I know I can achieve something like that using `sys.exc_info()` in my
exception handler and re-raising the exception once outside, but that seems
messy, as I have to set a flag in the except clause to remember to handle the
error afterwards. Is there a better way?

```
exc = None
try:
    ...
except sqlite3.Error:
    exc = sys.exc_info()
if exc:
    raise FileParseError("Invalid DB '%s': %s", fname, str(exc[1])), None, exc[2]
```

Platform: CPython 3.3 on Windows.

Similar question: [10555671](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555671) is exactly what I have now. I'm looking for something avoiding the double-traceback while also avoiding the manual `exc` flag setting and rechecking-after-except.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to chain your new exception off of the existing one. That can be done, using syntax introduced with [PEP 3134](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/). Alternatively, you could completely suppress the previous exception, using syntax added in [PEP 409](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/).

To chain the exceptions, give the caught exception a name with `as` in the `except` statement, then use the name with `from` at the end of your `raise` statement. Something like this:

```
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    raise FileParseError("Not a valid database: '%s'", fname) from e
```

If you want to completely suppress the sqlite error, rather than just translating it to another exception type, you can use `from None` in the `raise` statement:

```
except sqlite3.Error:
    raise FileParseError("Not a valid database: '%s'", fname) from None
```

The internal exception is still available when the context has been suppressed, but it will not be printed out in the traceback.

If you want to understand the issue of exception chaining in more detail, you should read the PEPs linked above, and perhaps also [PEP 415](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0415/) which describes the updated implementation of PEP 409.

Comment: One of those time machine moments for me, I didn't think there'd be such an elegant answer. I suggest everyone re-read [What's new in Py3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html), there's lots of good stuff there: ``SimpleNamespace``, ``faulthandler``, ``venv``, ``py`` on Windows, ...